# Entity Framework Reverse POCO generator vs code first for existing database (EF 6.1 or later)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had an existing data base with 200+ tables. I would to like to go with code first for existing db. Please suggest the best way.

Entity Framework Reverse POCO generator VS extension (OR) code first for existing database (EF 6.1 or later).

Comment: Why don't you **try them both** and then decide which tools works better for you??

Comment: Sure I will try both, but I would like to know the experience of others too.

Comment: I also would like to know the benefits of using either one or the other.  The tool built into Visual Studio is called ADO.NET Entity Data Model .... Code First from database.